# Integrate Mezzanine in an existing Django project

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm new to python. I've been working on Mezzanine and I've tried to integrate it with my existing Django project.

As told in the FAQs of Mezzanine I updated the `settings.py` of my Django project and couldn't figure out what is the exact update in the `urls.py` of my Django project.

I went through the internet and the related questions on stackoverflow but couldn't figure out the exact solution for integrating Mezzanine with another Django project.

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example here of `urls.py`: https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/project_template/project_name/urls.py

This note is important for you:

```
# MEZZANINE'S URLS
# ----------------
# ADD YOUR OWN URLPATTERNS *ABOVE* THE 
# ``mezzanine.urls`` INCLUDES A *CATCH 
# FOR PAGES, SO URLPATTERNS ADDED BELOW
# WILL NEVER BE MATCHED!
# If you'd like more granular control o
# ``mezzanine.urls``, go right ahead an
# from it, and use them directly below 
# ``mezzanine.urls``.
("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
```

Comment: how should I use it in my existing_djangoProject's 'urls.py'?
Basically, what exactly should I do to make this mezzanine project part of my existing_djangoProject or say how can I make mezzanine work as an app in a project?

Comment: i haven't worked with mezzanine but to my understanding you should include `("^", include("mezzanine.urls"))` to your url patterns